# Flex: need help implementing custom component code for dashed lines

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm new to Flex, and I've been trying to figure out how to use the following code for creating dashed lines in Flex 4.

http://riarange.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/how-to-create-a-dotted-line-or-dashed-line-in-flex-4/

I was hoping someone who knew Flex better could simply provide a complete (minimum) example that uses this code to draw a dashed line. I'm having trouble putting the pieces together, and I think the author assumed some basic knowledge that I lack. If I had a working example I could figure out how to adapt it to my needs.

Thanks in advance for any comments/help. If there's better code for dashed lines, would love to know.

UPDATE:

I placed the custom component code into a DottedLine.mxml file in the com directory. Now, I'm getting an error that appears at the `<components:Group>` line that says: `Could not resolve <components:Group> to a component implementation.`

```
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:components="com.*"
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:com="com.*">

<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    [Bindable]
    public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {Month:1, Profit:2000, Expenses:1500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.05, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.1, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.15, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.2, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.25, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.3, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.35, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.4, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.45, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.5, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.55, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.6, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.65, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.7, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.75, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:2.8, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:300},
    {Month:2.85, Profit:1000, Expenses:500, Amount:450},
    {Month:2.9, Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
    {Month:6, Profit:1500, Expenses:500, Amount:300}
    ]);

]]></fx:Script>

<mx:Panel title="Line Chart With Strokes">

    <mx:LineChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{expenses}" showDataTips="true" seriesFilters="{new Array}">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Month" yField="Expenses" displayName="Expenses">
                <mx:lineStroke>
                    <mx:SolidColorStroke id="s1" color="0xBD171B" weight="4"/>
                </mx:lineStroke>
            </mx:LineSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries xField="Month" yField="Amount" displayName="Amount">
                <components:Group>
                    <components:DottedLine width="500" height="2" dotColor="0xFFFFFF" dotWidth="3" dotAlpha="1" />      
                </components:Group>
            </mx:LineSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:LineChart>
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}" direction="horizontal"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

Comment: That example looks so complete to me; I'm not sure what you're missing.

Comment: Well, that's good I guess, it must be something obvious then. I'll edit the posting to show what I've done to try to implement it.

Comment: With regard to the errors you're getting, the one about components means that you don't have that namespace defined in the root node of the component you're trying to use the components prefix for.  It should be defined as the package that the DottedLine class lives in.  If the DottedLine class has the correct package name based on it's location in the project then simply doing a ctrl+space after <DottedLine should add the prefix and the namespace definition to the root node.

Comment: With regard to the mx:Script being unknown, since you're using Flex 4+ this has been changed to fx:Script in the new versions of Flex (greater than 3).

Comment: One other thing to be aware of is that in Flex 3 you could declare things like <mx:String id="someString"/> and that would be treated as a Bindable public variable, in Flex 4 you can do the same but anything that isn't a visual component in MXML has to be in the fx:Declarations block (sort of a nice way to distinguish those I think)

Comment: Shaun, great catch on the fx:Script. No error there now! Regarding the component error, should there be a class file for DottedLine somewhere? i just copied the code into the script block I already had, perhaps I should have placed it in an mxml file instead and named it DottedLine?

Comment: OK, I copied the custom component code into it's own file and updated the question above to reflect this. Still getting an error.

Comment: I haven't solved this, but I realize the above code will simply produce a straight dashed line rather than what I really wanted, which was a dashed line for a set of (x,y) points to use in a Line Chart. Shaun's comment's in the answer below contains a link that I'll try to use next to achieve this.

Comment: I also added another link below, from the quietly scheming website, that looks promising.

Comment: Yah I think the quietlyscheming one was what I was thinking of initially when I said there was something better out there.  If you pasted the DottedLine file into the same folder structure as the package name says then it should auto-import for you in flash builder/eclipse should end up with something like xmlns:business="com.shaunhusain.business.*" in the top level node of the MXML file, where com.shaunhusain.business would be the package/folder name.  then anywhere it sees <business:Something it looks for Something in com/shaunhusain/business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did these in Flex 3 but believe they should both work in Flex 4 too, there're other examples out there that are better than what I have and what you posted but it really depends on how you're going to apply the dashed lines.  If this doesn't help let me know and I'll try to clarify:
http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestDashedLines/index.html

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestDashedLines/index2.html

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestDashedLines/srcview/

What I've got here is two applications in one project, the first page is the output using the SimpleDashedLine class which is made for basically drawing an HRule but with dashes.  The second is for drawing arbitrary straight lines on top of other objects graphics.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, the first link has some very nice capabilities for dashed lines. My application plots scientific x,y data, and so would need a way to plot a line series using dashed lines. Would your code be a good fit for this?

Comment: Hi ggkmath, Yah the 2nd version in DrawExternalDashedLine should do the trick.  With Flex 4 you might want to look into using a Path if my class causes any sort of performance over-head (it's not really all that complicated so I don't think it'd be an issue but I haven't tried using it outside of plotting about 30 things on a map so depends on how complex your graph drawing is, also you'll want to probably account for the place one line ends with regard to a starting remaining dash space)

Comment: The first version, although it has some more options is only meant for drawing flat lines since dealing with the rectangular rotation is a pain.

Comment: This looks like it might be better: http://www.cartogrammar.com/blog/drawing-dashed-lines-with-actionscript-3/

Comment: Mostly it just irked me that it wasn't a totally trivial thing to do in Flex and we had it as part of our designs so I decided to tackle it myself, but there are some good one's out there if you look around for a bit, Grant Skinner, James Ward, Peter DeHaan, Ted Patrick and others have lots of good examples of Flex stuff, and deep knowledge (since you mentioned you're new to Flex figured I'd mention these names, bytearray.org is also good).

Comment: My app will plot many thousands of points, so performance is key. I know, Flex isn't ideally suited for this, but I will have to live with whatever it can provide.

Comment: You may want to do some math to figure out what kind of granularity you can actually display given the amount of pixels you have on a screen, if a display is only 1440x900 for example you can at most display 1440 independent values and a range from 0 to 900 assuming you use the entire screen.  With a big problem like that you might be best off "paging" the data so only certain sections are visible at a time or averaging the points to a data set that will fit on screen.  For financial data you need to be careful but keep in mind the possible limitations.

Comment: Drawing in Flex can be done very efficiently though, we deal with thousands of rows of data for the projects I'm on as well, it's just a matter of figuring out what work should be done by a service layer to get things in order before you pass them along to Flex for display versus what load is acceptable on the client (also depends on their machines versus the server)

Comment: Interesting, I had to manually draw about 50 minor tick mark labels on a LogAxis data canvas and the time to render suffered quite a bit. Thanks for all of your comments.

Comment: I found another potential dashed-line link for those interested: http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/dashes/index.html  The source code is here:  http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/dashes/srcview/index.html . To get working for Flex4, you'll need to modify the GraphicsUtils.as file to `import flash.geom.Point;` as well as `import flash.geom.Rectangle;` then change the line of code producing an error to: `stroke.apply(target, new Rectangle(), new Point());`